# <div> Element styling such that it can give a rotated and tilted effect

Tags: html, css

Hi i wanted to know how can the tilted style of the header section present in the image can be recreated using  element and CSS?

[image: this is what i wanted to create]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFEF4C;
}

#header {
  background-color: #FF3578;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

i want to get rid of those yellow gaping and want the header div to cover all the upper area....but i dont know how stupid of me

Comment: Sample code and your try required!

Comment: k will add it in a min giving the problem a second try

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding `margin` property in your code check this out:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: #FFEF4C;
    }
    
    #header {
      background-color: #FF3578;
      height: 300px;
      margin-top: -30px;
      transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header"></div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Note that `margin-top: -30px;` did the magic.

Comment: i wanted the other area to be covered as well the remain yellow portion

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFEF4C;
}

#header {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,#FF3578 49.5%,transparent 50%);
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```